# 60's-70's movie: home appliances revolting against the owners

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

My children asked me about the oldest movie I can remember (as a kid). It is a movie from before 1977 (probably mid 60's - early 70's) about a house where (children? owners?) were not taking care of the home appliances (I do not remember how exactly, but I think by not cleaning them, etc.)

**This home equipment, one day, decided to revolt against the owners and attack them.** I am sure the TV was part of the plot, and probably a vacuum cleaner.

I know that sounds like a comedy but it was not one, and what is left of the 5-6 years old boy in me is still terrified. Sorry for not having more details but my brain probably erased them.

It may have been a short movie (*The Twilight Zone* - like) and it was broadcast in Europe (in France I think, may have been Poland or Germany). I tried to Google for "home appliance attack" and this indeed brings a movie, but from the 00's.

Comment: Probably going to be hard to search for, as a lot of home appliances in the 60s and 70s were revolting.  The only one that springs to mind is the 80s movie Pulse but that's quite a bit after your time frame.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking [Maximum Overdrive](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091499/), but that's also too late, being released in 1986.  But it does feature appliances (and all other machines) turning on humans...

Comment: The wonderful short story "No One" by Diana Wynne Jones (found in the book "Unexpected Magic") has some similarities.  Except that the appliances are fighting against intruders who are attempting a kidnapping (not against the owners), and are led by the title character, a robot with the very useful name "No One."  (Obviously not what you're looking for, but might be of interest.)

Answer (score 15):

You may be thinking of the 1965 Benny Hill skit *One Step Behind*:

The skit exposits a movie in which appliances become monsters and attack a family.  It is, as one might expect given the milieu, cheesy.

I also watched it at a young age, and it gave me nightmares.

Answer (score 9):

You may be thinking of *The Twilight Zone* episode ["A Thing about Machines"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734551/?ref_=tt_urv).

> Bartlett Finchley is an odd man, a writer who contributes to food magazines and the like. He lives alone and is always it seems in need of a repairman for one piece of household equipment or another. As time has gone by, he seems to be in a constant battle with machines - his typewriter, his television - which all have the same message for him: get out of the house. He has no intention of doing so however and the battle begins.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but there was a 1978 Star Wars parody called [Hardware Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_Wars) where home appliances played a big role. The plot, if you can call it that, is quite different, however.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty long shot, but your description sounds a little like [The Twonky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twonky), which came out in the early 1950s. There's a TV that turns out to be able to do all kinds of things, and is determined to take charge of the life of the protagonist. It's intended to be a comedy, but the story is pretty creepy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are thinking of *[Demon Seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed)*, a great film.

True high octane nightmare fuel.  The Proteus AI takes over the house, builds a battle droid, kills a guy, makes a replicate of her to dissuade her husband from bothering its machinations, rapes a woman and impregnates her with a clone of her late daughter and uploads its mind into the child's body.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is a French movie called [Le démon dans l'île](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083863/) (apparently "Demon of the Island" in English), from 1983. I remember a lady being killed by her (unplugged) oven, played straight.

I rented it with friends in the late 1980s, for laughs, during our *Toxic Avenger* phase when we were about 18. But I can imagine it being impressive and disturbing to a child.

Answer (score 0):

A (slightly) more recent one...
*Pulse* (1988)
A boy tries to warn his father that they are being menaced by a malevolent pulse of electricity that moves from house to house, terrorizing the residents.

[image]