# 50s (or earlier) science fiction/horror story: narrator witnesses household machines turning on people, is unsure whether his car would hurt him

Tags: story-identification

The story which I read in about 1950 has to do with a narrator who has witnessed ordinary household machines in his home town rising up and attacking their owner/operators. Toasters, washing machines, vacuum cleaners, hair dryers in beauty salon.  NO computers, or aliens from outer space.

It ends with him holed up in his house planning to drive away in his car at night. "She'd never turn on me would she?"

Comment: I think that this story was "covered" in The Outer Limits.  I seem to recall seeing a story based on this in black and white.

Comment: @ShadoCat the one mentioned over at [60's-70's movie: home appliances revolting against the owners](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208953/98028), maybe?

Comment: I've read Skirmish but can't find anything at all about the Robert Bloch story, anyone know which anthologies it's in?

Comment: @DannyMcG Oops. No wonder you can't find it, I messed up the title. The title of the Robert Bloch story is ["It Happened Tomorrow"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98155). It's available at the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/details/Astonishing_Stories_v04n03_1943-02) and [here](https://archive.org/details/Super_Science_Stories_v08n02_1951-06).

Comment: The classic stories about rebellious machines are "It Happened Tomorrow" (Robert Bloch, 1943) and "Skirmish" (Clifford Simak, 1950) but the endings don't match your description, they are definitely not the story you remember reading. [I've corrected the title of Robert Bloch's story, which I erroneously gave as "It Happened Yesterday" in a previous version of this comment.]

Comment: Well I've read the Bloch story now (cheers for link) and it wasn't the story me, and probably the OP, had in mind. There is definitely dialogue between the protagonist and his car about him waxing and polishing it every Sunday, being very proud of it, and him buying it "the swell French horn". This gets the car to stop trying to enter the foyer of his building to crush him

Comment: Could it have been a poem: "Nightmare Number Three" by Stephen Vincent Binet?

Answer (score 5):

The poem "[Nightmare Number Three](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?105219)" by Stephen Vincent Binet is somewhat similar sounding:

> We had expected everything but revolt

> And I kind of wonder myself when they started thinking--

> But there’s no dice in that now.

> I’ve heard fellow say

> They must have planned it for years and maybe they did.
>
> Looking back, you can find little incidents here and there,

> Like the concrete-mixer in Jersey eating the wop

> Or the roto press that printed 'Fiddle-dee-dee!'

> In a three-color process all over Senator Sloop,

> Just as he was making a speech. The thing about that

> Was, how could it walk upstairs? But it was upstairs,

> Clicking and mumbling in the Senate Chamber.

> They had to knock out the wall to take it away

> And the wrecking-crew said it grinned.

> It was only the best

> Machines, of course, the superhuman machines,

> The ones we’d built to be better than flesh and bone,

> But the cars were in it, of course . . .

[...]

> (I wish I hadn’t looked into the beauty-parlor

> And seen what was happening there.

> But those are female machines and a bit high-strung.)

> Oh, we’ll settle down. We’ll arrange it. We’ll compromise.

> It won’t make sense to wipe out the whole human race.

> Why, I bet if I went to my old Plymouth now

> (Of course you’d have to do it the tactful way)

> And said, 'Look here! Who got you the swell French horn?'

> He wouldn’t turn me over to those police cars;

> At least I don’t think he would.

> Oh, it’s going to be jake.

From [PoemHunter.com](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/nightmare-number-three/)

Comment: Yep. That's what I was thinking of, don't know if it is the one OP was looking for .... Blast from the past there! A long long time since I read it. And also the bit about the window cleaner and his own hoist